# Jquery Datatables with special table header

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to make a table using jquery datatable with the header shown below

```
      <table id="tableau" class="display" width="100%" align="center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th rowspan="2"></th>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th rowspan="2"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This works great alone but, when I try it with jquery datatables it doesn't work at all. Nothing shows up except the table header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#tableau').DataTable( {
    "scrollY":          "500px",
    "scrollCollapse":   true,
    "autoWidth":        true,
    "paging":           false,
    "processing":       false,
    "info":             false,
    "ordering":         false,
    "searching":        false,
    "data": [
             {
                 "ta":  "ta",
                 "tb":  "tb",
                 "tc":  "tc",
                 "td":  "td",
                 "te":  "te",
                 "tf":  "tf",
                 "tg":  "tg",
                 "th":  "th"
             },
             {
                 "ta":  "ta",
                 "tb":  "tb",
                 "tc":  "tc",
                 "td":  "td",
                 "te":  "te",
                 "tf":  "tf",
                 "tg":  "tg",
                 "th":  "th"
             },
     ],
    "columns": [
        {
            "data":             null,
            "defaultContent":   ''
        },
        {   "data":             "ta" },
        {   "data":             null,
            "defaultContent":   ''
        },
        {   "data":             "tb" },
        {   "data":             null,
            "defaultContent":   ''
        },
        {   "data":             null,
            "defaultContent":   ''
        },
        { "data":               "tc" },
        {   "data":             null,
            "defaultContent":   ''
        }
    ],
} );
```

Comment: what you have tried could post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g3vwp37w/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Test</td>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great alone but I have forgotten to tell you that I am using jquery datatables in this table and it doesn't work out great

Comment: You should update the question on how the plugin works.. how are you trying to use it?